# Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan, ensure an appropriate bean is registered

Tags: java, android, spring, tomcat

I am able to run my application as Spring Boot Application in Eclipse, but while deploying on tomcat I am getting error while context loading as: **Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan, ensure an appropriate bean is registered**

**Stack trace:**

2014-11-04 09:47:42.758  INFO 7808 --- [ost-startStop-1] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)

2014-11-04 09:47:42.779 ERROR 7808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan, ensure an appropriate bean is registered.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
        at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(EntityScanRegistrar.java:124)
        at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(EntityScanRegistrar.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:778)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2014-11-04 09:47:42.786  INFO 7808 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationCo
ntext@54a6621c: startup date [Tue Nov 04 09:47:38 IST 2014]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6e65b791
2014-11-04 09:47:42.794  INFO 7808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2014-11-04 09:47:42.806  INFO 7808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService
2014-11-04 09:47:42.808  INFO 7808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean  : Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
Nov 04, 2014 9:47:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xyz]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan, ensure an appropriate bean is registered.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
        at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(EntityScanRegistrar.java:124)
        at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(EntityScanRegistrar.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:778)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

Nov 04, 2014 9:47:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\xyz.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardCo
ntext[/xyz]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 04, 2014 9:47:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\xyz.war has finished in 37,169 ms

Comment: noticed now this thread: I'm experiencing a similar error when deploying on tomcat (see my thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609791/spring-data-rest-unable-to-configure-localcontainerentitymanagerfactorybean-fr) : did you ever find a solution to the problem?