# Spring Data Rest: "Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan"

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7, spring-data-rest

I've got a REST service spring boot application, consisting into two separate maven projects:

1. The first one `myapp-data` includes Spring Data JPA + Spring Data Rest Entities and Rest Repositories class definitions (I've isolated these in a separate maven project since I use them also in other applications besides my REST service).
2. The secon `myapp-services` is a Spring Boot application that basically contains main method + configuration to expose the above Spring Data Rest repositories as REST endpoints.

If I run this in a local development environment (STS Eclipse, launching `mvn  spring-boot:run` on my local development machine) everything seems to work fine, but when I deploy it as a war on a staging tomcat environment (tomcat7 under ubuntu 14.04) I got the exception in the box below. Note that besides this the difference in the two deployments consists only in different settings of in `application.properties` (db connection, logging levels, etc.).

Before some code changes I made (in previous versions for instance I used normal JPA repositories and custom Rest Controllers instead of Spring Data Rest repositories) the application deployed fine both in development and staging environments. The problem probably started to arise when I added the Spring Data Rest repositories, but I'm not 100% sure of this since I deployed in the staging environment after a number of other minor changes in a row.

This is the exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan, ensure an appropriate bean is registered.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
        at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EntityScanRegistrar.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:692)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the main Application class for the `myapp-services` project:

```
package eu.myapp.services;

@ComponentScan(value="eu.myapp")
@EnableJpaRepositories("eu.myapp.data")
@EntityScan(value="eu.myapp.data")
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyappServicesApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyappServicesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

where `eu.myapp.data` is the package defined in the `myapp-data` project included as maven dependency, containing Entity and Repository classes definitions.

In my service project configuration I use Spring Security with a custom UserDetailsService (don't know whether this could be relevant, .. it worked in previous deployments, so probably it is not).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's too late but I'm going to tell you what I have done to fix this problem for future references.

Apparently the problem is related with Spring Security an the custom UserDetailsService.

I think that there is a conflict between the main application class and your configuration class for SpringSecurity once they try to access to the database layer at the same time.

To fix this, you can add the tag @Order(1) to the main class and a different one (@Order(30) for example) to the security class.

I don't know why it only happens when you deploy the application into a webserver (Glassfish 4.1.1 for me).

I hope it helps.

Other references:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1008

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (I see it only now since I was on holidays on the past weeks).

In the end, I decided to deploy the service in production too as a standalone (embedded tomcat) spring boot app, instead on installing in on the production servers' tomcat instance. Since besides solving my exception, this approach turned out to have many other advantages I decided to stick to this and didn't investigate the issue further.

In any case, since I'm interesting in verifying if your solution works, as soon as I have some time I'll give it a try and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will help anyone but...

I had the same issue and it wound up being a class that

`extends org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer`

that was causing the issue. I was able to refactor the code and take that out, eliminating the error.

Hope someone finds this useful.